# Проблема с наследованием Python вк бот

Tags: python, ооп, бот, вконтакте, наследование

Пишу бота для вк и столкнулся с проблемой

Есть классы

```
class Bot(DefaultCommands, VipCommands):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vk = ... # Аттрибут по умолчанию
        self.event ... # Аттрибут значение которого меняется 


class DefaultCommands(Utils):
    def command_1(self):
        # использование vk, event из Bot
        ...


class VipCommands(Utils):
    def command_1(self):
        # использование vk, event из Bot
        ...

class Utils:
    def send_message(self):
        # использование vk, event
        ...
```

Так вот есть вопросы

1. Как сделать чтоб был доступ к vk, event у родительских классов (знаю можно через super(), но проблема в том что event динамичекский, есть еще вариант просто передавать в аргументы методам, но он мне кажется слишком глупым )
2. Правильно ли я делаю, что передаю Utils каждому классу с командами

В общем вопрос главный как это всё по умному сделать, чтоб соответствовало всем стандартам